# Delete an object from object array {}

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to build a 'to-do' list for a task. Initial state must have the structure shown on code. I'm new to coding and cannot figure out how to delete an object from an object array.

I have tried using the .pop() and .filter() methods but they are not accepted because the object array is an object of objects and not an actual array. I also tried to find the index and do delete state.data[index] but the console sends an error message "cannot update component while rendering other component". Rest of the code works fine when I don't include the handleDeleteClick() function and remove the deleteItem reducer. Here's the code:

```
//the following creates an item component for each item in the 'to do' list

import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { editItem, deleteItem, completedItem } from '../store/todoSlice';



const TodoItem = ({ id, content, completed }) => {
 const dispatch = useDispatch();

//initialising state for items that the user wants to edit
const [edit, setEdit] = useState(false);
const [newItem, setNewItem] = useState(content);
const [finishedItem, setFinishedItem]= useState(false);


//function to call deleteItem reducer
 const handleDeleteClick = () => {
    dispatch(deleteItem({id, content}))
}


//function to call editItem reducer
 const onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    dispatch(
        editItem({id, newItem, completed}));
    
    //setting edit and finished state back to null
    setNewItem("");
    setEdit(false);
    setFinishedItem(false);
};

//function to call completedItem reducer
const completedTask = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    dispatch(
        completedItem({id, content, completed})
    );
    setFinishedItem(true);
};


//if edit state is true, return <input> element to edit the item requested
if(edit){
    return (
        <form>
            <input id="editInput" value={newItem} onChange= {(e) => setNewItem(e.target.value)} placeholder="Edit your item"/>
            <button onClick = {onSubmit} type='submit' id="submitButton">ADD</button>
        </form>
        
    )
}

//if edit state is false and finishedItem is true, return same list and add an id to completed button
if(!edit && finishedItem) {
    return(
        <div id="itemSection">
        
        <li id="item">{content} 
            <button onClick= {handleDeleteClick(content)} className="function">DELETE</button>
            <button onClick={() => setEdit(true)} className="function"> EDIT</button>
            <button onClick={completedTask} id="completed">COMPLETED</button>
        
        </li>
    </div>

    )
}

//else, return <ul> element for each 'todo' item with 3 buttons to edit, delete or complete task 
return (
    <div id="itemSection">
        
        <li id="item">{content} 
            <button onClick={handleDeleteClick()} className="function">DELETE</button>
            <button onClick={() => setEdit(true)} className="function"> EDIT</button>
            <button onClick={completedTask}>COMPLETED</button>
        
        </li>
    </div>
);
};

export default TodoItem;


//the following creates state slice for the todos object array

import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const toDoSlice = createSlice({
name: "todos",

//set initial state of object array
initialState: {
    nextId: 2,
    data:
    {
        1: {
            content: 'Content 1',
            completed: false
        }
    }
   
},

reducers: {
    //function to add item to object array
    addItem: (state, action) => {
        state.data = 
            {
                ...state.data,
                [state.nextId]: {
                    content: action.payload.content,
                    completed: false
                }
            }
        state.nextId += 1;
        
    },

    //function to delete item from object array
    deleteItem: (state, action) => {
            const index= action.payload.id;
            delete state.data[index];
    
    },
        


    //function to edit item from object array
    editItem: (state, action) => {
       state.data =
       {
        ...state.data,
        [action.payload.id]: {
            content: action.payload.newItem,
            completed: false
        }
       }

     },

     //function to complete item from object array
     completedItem: (state, action) => {
        state.data =
        {
         ...state.data,
         [action.payload.id]: {
             content: action.payload.content,
             completed: true
         }
        }


     }
}     

});

export const {addItem, editItem, deleteItem, completedItem} =
 toDoSlice.actions;

export default toDoSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your example is that you're setting up `data` as an object. You should not do that, unless you have a good reason to, which doesn't seem to be the case.

Instead of:

```js
createSlice({
  //...
  initialState: {
    nextId: 2,
    data: { //  object
      1: {
        content: 'Content 1',
        completed: false
      }
    }
  }
  // ...
})
```

you should use:

```js
createSlice({
  // ...
  initialState: {
    nextId: 2,
    data: [{ //  array
      content: 'Content 1',
      completed: false
    }]
  }
  // ...
})
```

Now `data` has all the array methods available, including `.filter()`. ***<sup>1</sup>***

---

If, for whatever reason, you want to keep `data` as an object, you could use

```js
delete data[key]
```

where `key` is the object property you want to delete. (e.g: if you want to delete `1`, use `delete state.data.1` or `delete state.data['1']`).

But my strong advice is to change `data` to an array.

---

**Notes**:

***<sup>1</sup>*** - Note you will need to modify all your reducers to deal with the array. For example:

```js
{
  reducers: {
    addItem: (state, action) => {
      state.data.push({
        content: action.payload.content,
        completed: false
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Most likely, you won't need `state.nextId` anymore. That's the advantage of dealing with arrays, you don't need to know what `key`/`index` you're assigning to when you add an item.

You will likely need to add an unique identifier to each item (e.g: an `id`) so you can find it by that `id` when you want to delete or modify it.

Comment: thank you! I do agree but the code is for a task that I need to submit and they have asked me to initialise data as an object. I have tried the delete method but the console sends an error message "cannot update component while rendering other component". Would you be able to let me know how I can fix that error?

Comment: Not unless you provide a *runnable* [mcve]. I can't debug errors I'm not able to see. I suggest using codesandbox.io (or similar) to [import](https://codesandbox.io/docs/learn/getting-started/your-first-sandbox#import-local-projects-via-cli) your local project. Also, the request to use an object there  is rather unusual, to say the least. Is this for learning purposes? Because if it is, you should probably discuss with your teacher, not ask for a solution on [SO]. If it's for learning purposes, the main purpose is that you learn.

Comment: thank you for letting me know how to do it :). Here's the link to my codesandbox project: https://codesandbox.io/s/e4clze

Comment: See it working [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/task2-forked-nfv326?file=/src/store/todoSlice.js:667-754). You had another ***big*** problem: `onClick={handleDeleteClick(content)}`. This executes the handler when the component is mounted, not when the button is clicked, and assigns the returned value of the handler (which is `undefined` in this case) to `onClick`. Should be `onClick={() => handleDeleteClick(content)}`.